# simplest way to get an ubuntu virtual machine w/ ssh server on my network

Tags: osx, virtual-machine

I have an OSX box and I'd like to just get a fresh install of Ubuntu to use remotely over SSH. That's all. But I'd like to get that on the same box without in anyway altering my existing OSX environment (i.e. I want to just run an Ubuntu VM or Docker).

What's the simplest (fewest steps) way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) with an [Ubuntu Vbox Image](http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/), it is a layer on top of VirtualBox and provides pre-made images called [boxes](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes.html), amongst them [Ubuntu images](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/).